# mongoose returns empty array (i tried whatever i could)

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Schema: File name: Login.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LoginSchema = new Schema({
  uname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pass: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Login = mongoose.model('login', LoginSchema);
```

index.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://mongo:27017/docker-node-mongo',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  
const Login = require('./models/Login');

app.post('/',(req,res) => {
    
    
        const newLogin = new Login({
            uname: req.body.uname,
            pass: req.body.pass
          });
        console.log(newLogin);
        newLogin.save();

    Login.find({},function (err, logins) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("cool: ",logins);
      });
    res.redirect('/main');
});
```

Heres the output in the console:
MongoDB Connected

{ _id: 5fab21a3931694001290326e, uname: 'guest', pass: 'guest' }

cool:  []

---

The output of .find() is empty. AND just before I have put in an entry and that entry even shows in the console. I saw the plural thing and its not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongodb save() is asynchronous so it doesn't wait for the saving of the document. When it tries to find the document it can't be found it because it hasn't been saved yet. You can use async/await so it waits for the saving process and then proceeds.

```
app.post('/', async (req,res) => {
        
            const newLogin = new Login({
                uname: req.body.uname,
                pass: req.body.pass
              });
            console.log(newLogin);
            await newLogin.save();
    
        Login.find({},function (err, logins) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log("cool: ",logins);
          });
        res.redirect('/main');
    });
```

Comment: thanks i have another question: in the schema i want to hardcode a predefined username and password as guest,guest. How to do this?? Thanks

Comment: You can default value in the schema. For example default:"Guest"